# Accessing a member value set in previous window other then using a static member

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to access a member value in another window or across multiple windows. Is this only possible with static variables? I have two `WPF Windows`. *MainWindow* and *TargetWindow*.

Here is an example:

Member Class:

```
 class Variables
    {
        private string _userInput;

        public Variables(string input)
        {
            _userInput = input;
        }

        public string UserInput
        {
            set
            {
                _userInput = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _userInput;
            }
        }
    }
```

Call and pass value to member in window:

```
 private void txtMainEntry_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Variables variable;

            //Passing user input to class member via constructor
            variable = new Variables(txtMainEntry.Text);

            //Get value from class member
            showUserEntry.Text = variable.UserInput;

            if (e.Key == Key.Return & variable.UserInput == "Hello World")
            {
                TargetWindow tWindow = new TargetWindow();
                tWindow.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

How do I access the same value in another window without using static member:

```
public partial class TargetWindow : Window
{
    public TargetWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void lblDisplayVariableValue_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //How do I call and get the value of the class member 
        //set in the previous form
    }
}
```

Comment: If you logically need information to build up your form, you should get it in the constructor (don't forget to have an available default constructor still, and handle null's throughout your code, or it might get messy with the designer).

Comment: I would have considered my ineraction design, and see if I could fit the windows in one page/view instead. Other than that, I agree with @YoryeNathan, if you need several windows.

Comment: you may also use attached properties if it is not possible for you to modify constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of approach other then using static value, I have listed a few of them

**Approach 1 `(Constructors)`**

```
    private void txtMainEntry_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Variables variable;

        //Passing user input to class member via constructor
        variable = new Variables(txtMainEntry.Text);

        //Get value from class member
        showUserEntry.Text = variable.UserInput;

        if (e.Key == Key.Return & variable.UserInput == "Hello World")
        {
            TargetWindow tWindow = new TargetWindow(variable);
            tWindow.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    public partial class TargetWindow : Window
    {
        Variables variable ;

        public TargetWindow(Variables variable)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.variable = variable;
        }

        private void lblDisplayVariableValue_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //use variable field
        }
    }
```

**Approach 2 `(Properties)`**

```
    private void txtMainEntry_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Variables variable;

        //Passing user input to class member via constructor
        variable = new Variables(txtMainEntry.Text);

        //Get value from class member
        showUserEntry.Text = variable.UserInput;

        if (e.Key == Key.Return & variable.UserInput == "Hello World")
        {
            TargetWindow tWindow = new TargetWindow();
            tWindow.Variable = variable;
            tWindow.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    public partial class TargetWindow : Window
    {
        public Variables Variable { get; set; }

        public TargetWindow(Variables variable)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void lblDisplayVariableValue_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //use Variable property
        }
    }
```

`Note:` above samples are assuming that you have to pass the `variable`, you may change as per your needs

other solution is to use attached properties, if above are not feasible then let me know I'll provide a sample for the same.

Comment: Thanks! This should do it or at-least get me started.
Thank you again!